# How do I do an atomic INSERT IF NOT EXISTS equivalent in sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite

The questions says it all really.

I have a table and I want to insert a row if it doesn't already exist.
or should I just do an insert and if the key constraint is violated then ignore it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use INSERT OR IGNORE: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a trigger that fires before INSERTs and discards the duplicate row, something along the lines of...

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE INSERT on your_table
FOR EACH ROW WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE id = NEW.id)
BEGIN
  SELECT RAISE(IGNORE);
END;
```

Comment: I think this would be exceedingly slow and inefficient, but thanks for the suggestion.  It seems insert or ignore does what I require.

Comment: Try "marginally faster."  Just for laughs, I benchmarked it both ways.  `INSERT OR IGNORE` took, on average, 5% longer than the trigger.  I have a theory why that is but would have to dig through the SQLite source to confirm it.